# Update multiple rows with same value in where clause - MySQL, Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot

I'm using Spring boot with MySQL in my application.

Here is a code sample from my DAO file:

```
// update respective entries in the project_skill relational table
for (long skillID : newProjectRequestVO.getRequiredSkills()) {
    skillRepository.updateProjectSkill(skillID, id);
}
```

`newProjectRequestVO.getRequiredSkills()` is an array of integers (eg: `[2,3]`) and `id` is an integer (eg: `2`).

Here is a snippet from Repository file:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value = "update project_skill set skill_id = ?1 where project_id = ?2", nativeQuery = true)
public int updateProjectSkill(long skill_id, long project_id);
```

`project_skill` table roughly looks like this:

```
+------------+--------------+
| project_id |   skill_id   | 
+------------+--------------+
|  1         | 1            | 
|  1         | 3            |
|  2         | 2            |
|  2         | 4            |
|  3         | 1            |
|  3         | 3            |
+------------+--------------+
```

After running my application with `[2,3]` as the array and `2` as the id, My table becomes something like this:

```
+------------+--------------+
| project_id |   skill_id   | 
+------------+--------------+
|  1         | 1            | 
|  1         | 3            |
|  2         | 3            |
|  2         | 3            |
|  3         | 1            |
|  3         | 3            |
+------------+--------------+
```

i.e, All the rows having project_id as `2` gets replaced by the last element in the array, which is `3` in my case. But, what I am expecting is something like this:

```
+------------+--------------+
| project_id |   skill_id   | 
+------------+--------------+
|  1         | 1            | 
|  1         | 3            |
|  2         | 2            |
|  2         | 3            |
|  3         | 1            |
|  3         | 3            |
+------------+--------------+
```

At the same time, if I am having 3 elements in the array, the final value should be inserted in the table instead of updating the rows.

For [2,3,5], the table should be:

```
+------------+--------------+
| project_id |   skill_id   | 
+------------+--------------+
|  1         | 1            | 
|  1         | 3            |
|  2         | 2            |
|  2         | 3            |
|  2         | 5            |
|  3         | 1            |
|  3         | 3            |
+------------+--------------+
```

Comment: That's logical, what is the logic of which skill is replaced with which skill id of one project ?

Comment: I have a separate table for skill details, which has skill_id as the primary key. It's just a mapping table.

Comment: You didn't get it. You are updating every row of the project is in every update. Okay how you can easily solve it. Delete all existing skills mapping of project first then create new skills mapping.

Comment: It would be a little easier to follow if you used different scales for the two ids